# How to pass files to the master node?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've already written code in python to implement binary classification, and I want to parallelize this classification process based on different data files in my local computer using Apache-Spark. I have already done the following steps:

1. I've written the whole project containing 4 python files: "run_classifer.py" (used for running my classification application), "classifer.py" (used for binary classification), "load_params.py" (used for load the learning parameters for classification) and "preprocessing.py" (used for pre-processing data). The project also uses the dependency files: "tokenizer.perl" (used in preprocessing part) and "nonbreaking_prefixes/nonbreaking_prefix.en" (also used in preprocessing part).
2. The main part of my script file "run_classifer.py" is defined as follow,

   ```
   ### Initialize the Spark
   conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ruofan").setMaster("local")
   sc = SparkContext(conf = conf,
       pyFiles=['''All python files in my project as
                well as "nonbreaking_prefix.en" and "tokenizer.perl"'''])

   ### Read data directory from S3 storage, and create RDD
   datafile = sc.wholeTextFiles("s3n://bucket/data_dir") 

   ### Sent the application on each of the slave node
   datafile.foreach(lambda (path, content): classifier(path, content))
   ```

However, When I run my script "run_classifier.py", it seems like cannot find the file "nonbreaking_prefix.en". The following is the error I got:

> ERROR: No abbreviations files found in /tmp/spark-f035270e-e267-4d71-9bf1-8c42ca2097ee/userFiles-88093e1a-6096-4592-8a71-be5548a4f8ae/nonbreaking_prefixes

But I actually passed the file "nonbreaking_prefix.en" to the master node, and I have no ideas on the error. I would really appreciate if anyone helps me fix the problem.

Comment: Can you try `--files` option to distribute files for executors?

Comment: The pyfiles argument is meant only for Python files (normally `*.py`). I believe pyfiles works with egg files as well, so you might want to structure your code as a package, list the non-python files as a dependency, compile the package as an egg, and then include the egg in pyfiles.

Comment: @gonbe Thank you for your comments! Actually, I tried `./spark-submit --files=nonbreaking_prefix.en run_classifer.py`, but I still got the same error: `ERROR: No abbreviations files found in /tmp/spark-f035270e-e267-4d71-9bf1-8c42ca2097ee/userFiles-88093e1a-6096-4592-8a71-be5548a4f8ae/nonbreaking_prefixes`.

Comment: How about `--files=nonbreaking_prefixes/nonbreaking_prefix.en`, or remove directory structure?

Comment: @santon Thanks for your comments! I tried to use `./spark-submit --files=nonbreaking_prefix.en run_classifer.py`, but I still got the same error: `ERROR: No abbreviations files found in /tmp/spark-f035270e-e267-4d71-9bf1-8c42ca2097ee/userFiles-88093e1a-6096-4592-8a7‌​1-be5548a4f8ae/nonbreaking_prefixes`

Comment: @gonbe Thank you for your comments! I tried both of ways you mentioned, but still got the same error...

Comment: In the spark log do you see other errors? e.g. no such file, permission denied

Comment: @gonbe Thanks! Before I run my code, I've export the environment variables: `export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...` and `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...`, and I got the error mentioned before. Also, I don't think I have any other errors so far. I really cannot figure out why the code does not work with Spark.

Comment: Could you post output of `tree` /  `find .` from a project directory (where you run `spark-submit`) as well as the part of the `classifier` code where you access `nonbreaking_prefix.en`?

Comment: I see. You may want to how "abbreviations" file is searched and increase debug level of spark to see what files are distributed to the nodes. Nothing I can help further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload your files using `sc.addFile` and get path on a worker using `SparkFiles.get`:

```
from pyspark import SparkFiles

sc = (SparkContext(conf = conf,
    pyFiles=["All",  "Python", "Files",  "in",  "your", "project"])

# Assuming both files are in your working directory
sc.addFile("nonbreaking_prefix.en")
sc.addFile("tokenizer.perl")

def classifier(path, content):
   # Get path for uploaded files
   print SparkFiles.get("tokenizer.perl")

   with open(SparkFiles.get("nonbreaking_prefix.en")) as fr:
       lines = [line for line in fr]
```

Comment: @zeros323 Thank you so much for your great answers! `addFile()` is a great function to pass all dependent files to slave nodes! But I still get confused about the location of the file "location of nonbreaking_prefix.en" in function `addFile('location of nonbreaking_prefix.en')`. In specific, I put 'nonbreaking_prefix.en' in different locations, for example, s1='/root/nonbreaking_prefix.en' and s2='/root/spark/bin/nonbreaking_prefix.en'. In fact, `addFile(s2)` works very well. But for `addFile(s1)`, the slave nodes cannot find the location of the file. I'm wondering the reason of the problem.

Comment: I cannot check this right now but generally speaking `addFile` is a rather simple tool. If you need a complex structure it is better to use a distributed file system.