# How do I load files from a specific local path(whether in master node or slave node) in spark cluster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner of spark. Recently I am learning pySpark and trying to submit a simple application to spark cluster (I set up a cluster with 1 master and 1 worker). However, I don't know how to properly specify a path(for example a folder in my master node).

This is my code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

APP_NAME = "ImageResizer"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
    conf = conf.setMaster("spark://10.233.70.48:7077")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

s_list = sc.parallelize(os.listdir('.'))
s_jpg_list = s_list.filter(lambda f:f.endswith('.jpg'))

def resize_image(f):
    i = Image.open(f)
    size_64 = (64,64)
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
    i.thumbnail(size_64)
    out_path = 'resize/{}_64{}'.format(name, extension)
    i.save(out_path)
    return out_path

s_jpg_files = s_jpg_list.map(resize_image)
print('Converted Images:', s_jpg_files.collect())
```

I want to batch resize images from a folder in my master machine, the code takes all the contents within the folder that the python application locates. But when I submitted the application to spark, the system can not find the path.

then I tried:

```
s_list = sc.parallelize(os.listdir('/home/xxx/'))
```

seems I can still not access the desired folder(I don't know how to even specify master node or slave node when choosing the folder).

Can anyone please help me to revise the way I refer the path?

In addition, how can I refer to the machine where the job was submitted / The local directory on every machine /A shared network drive? Thank you so much!

Comment: Generally you use a HDFS share that is accessible by all nodes. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Jaco I setup a cluster with 1 master node and 1 worker node, wanting to batch resize images that stored in my master node. but I don't know how to direct to the desired path.  I tried                                                                s_list = sc.parallelize(os.listdir('hdfs://home/image/'))  but did't work

Comment: If a HDFS share is not an option, you can use `sc.addFile` and `SparkFiles.get` instead to submit files from your master node to your slave node. Have a look at the accepted answer for this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755992/how-to-pass-files-to-the-master-node.

Comment: @Jaco thank you. but can it achieve to get/add all files in a folder? I still do not get it. I will revise my original post to pose my complete code. It's a simple application but I don't know how to properly load files from my master machine. :)